# whitelist 127.0.0.1 on IPSEC Windows

Tags: windows, windows-server, ipsec

How do we whitelist the localhost 0r 127.0.0.1  on IPSec?

Currently I have two policy.
1. Block All IPs.
2. Permit some IP.

Rule number 1 has blocked localhost IP also.

Answer (score 0):

Your deny all rule should always be last in your list, that way your permitted IP rules will be reached first and executed.

Comment: Okay let me try.  I have created blocked and allowed rules but it did not apply anyhow.  because this server has been hacked before ,I am still figuring out why the IPSec did not work on this server while work on others

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer already. 
Inputting specific IP address 127.0.0.1 is not doable.
You can use the Add IP wizard on Permit function you have created earlier .

Select A Specific DNS Name -> Input 'localhost'

[DNS Name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SIZe.png)